# How to keep a pin LOW for a small amount of time after pushing a button and while device is booting?

Tags: esp8266, pins, reset, capacitors

### Context

I keep the board in deepsleep mode and want to wake it with different buttons. I need to know which button has been pushed on boot. The board is immediately put back in deepsleep mode afterward.

I've been able to reset the board and pull a pin LOW at the same time. (see circuit below). The reset pin is momentarily pulled low so it reset the board effectively.

I'm not an electronic engineer, just a hobbyist, so any other method to do something are always welcome.

### Problem

With the actual code/circuit, I *need* to hold the button until the device boot up so it can detect button was pushed but **I would like to be able to just push the button quickly** instead of having to hold it.

### Question

How to add some sort of delay that will "hold" the **SW-D5** button until the board boot?

Or anything that keep my D5 pin LOW for a short amount of time after the button has been pushed?

I think something in the range of 500 to 1000 milliseconds would be enough.

### My actual circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbKKgT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

### My code

```c
#include <Spi.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

int buttonPin = D5;

void setup() {
  // Read pin value as soon as possible after boot
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  int buttonValueAtBoot = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();

  if (buttonValueAtBoot == LOW) {
    Serial.println("D5 was pressed");

    // Do something useful here like making an HTTP request.
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);
  }

  // Avoid problem when the button is being hold
  while (digitalRead(buttonPin) == LOW) {
    // wait before going to deepsleep
    // or the capacitor will be drained
    delay(1);
  }

  Serial.println("going to sleep");
  ESP.deepSleep(0);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: write a pin to hold it down; `pinMode()` in `setup()` kicks in in about  200ms

Comment: @dandavis the problem is that the pin already changed its state back to normal once in `setup()`.Push `SW-D5` -> trigger reboot -> release `SW-D5` -> few hundreds of milliseconds later -> `setup()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple RC network should do the job.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIv8jX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Ok. A quick explanation of what we have here.  C1 and R1 are the same as you have at the moment for your reset circuit. R1 is the existing pullup resistor in the Wemos. R3 recharges the C1 when the button is released. It's effectively the pullup for the button.

D2 is to separate the two parts of the circuit. It prevents R3 from charging the capacitor C2.

The magic happens with C2 and R2. Pressing SW1 discharges C2, and the GPIO goes low.  When you release SW1 C2 charges up again through R2.  When the voltage across C2 rises to the V<sub>IH</sub> of the GPIO the GPIO will go high.

D1 is to protect the GPIO from the negative pulse you can get from C2 as it discharges.

Here's a simulation. Top line is the GPIO, bottom is RESET.

[image]

V<sub>IH</sub> for the ESP8266 is 0.75V<sub>IO</sub>, so 75% of 3.3V, or 2.475V.

The charge time of the capacitor C2 is calculated as T=RC, where T is the time taken to charge up to 63% of the supply voltage (2.08V)

With the shown values the time taken to rise to 63% of 3.3V will be 10,000 x 0.0001 seconds, or 1 second.  So to get to 75% it will take a little longer than 1 second.  75% is about 1.4T, so if T is 1 as in the above equation then it will take 1.4 seconds (1 * 1.4) to rise enough for the GPIO to register as HIGH.

Note these times are all from the moment you *release* the button. Reset has already happened before that time.

Also the internal pullup of the GPIO should be **disabled** otherwise it will also charge the capacitor and the charge time will be reduced. Since you don't know that resistor value it then becomes impossible to calculate what the charge time will be. Simplest to just disable it and only use the external resistor R2.

Comment: If the button is pressed twice, C1 will still be charged after the first press. Reset does not work. When and how can C1 be discharged?

Comment: Good point. It wants a pullup - and maybe a diode to isolate the two signals. I'll tweak it.

Comment: Not so long ago, circuits for me were hieroglyphs. Now I can look at them and appreciate their beauty, how they work, the reason of everything. The joy of learning.

Comment: @majenko thanks for the time you took for all those very appreciated explanations. Will it work if I use diode instead of Schottky diode? I will try your suggested circuit as soon as I receive bigger capacitor this week

Comment: Yes it should work with a silicon diode.

Comment: The use of a schottky for D2 is to keep the LOW voltage as low as possible. As long as it's below the VIL of the ESP8266 then it doesn't matter what the diode is. D1 is to try and match the ESD diode in the chip itself. If it's forward voltage is above the ESD diode's forward voltage the ESD diode will conduct instead of D1 - both making D1 pointless and possibly (though highly unlikely) endangering the ESD diode in the chip.

Comment: @Majenko I've disabled the pullup of the GPIO and everything start working as expected using the circuit you designed except that it reset as soon as I push the button, not when I release it. But it's not a big deal tho.. I've even been able to add a second button duplicating the circuit before D2 and adding diodes between the buttons and R3, C1 junction. Your help and explanations were really appreciated! Now I'll investigate to find why it's not working properly when battery powered. Thanks again

Comment: @Majenko how did you generate your simulation image?

Comment: @Remi Yes, reset as you press the button is normal. It's a low-going pulse. I use Falstad to do my simple simulations. http://www.falstad.com/circuit/

Comment: This is amazing. I've been trying to figure this out for a week, trying everything from latch to 555 timers to get this to work and you've done it with a simple capacitor. Thanks!!

Comment: @Majenko How would you modify this if you want multiple buttons to reset the same device but track them on different gpios?

Comment: You should be able to pretty much duplicate the entire circuit and connect multiple copies to the RESET pin.

Comment: You may want to separate the circuits out with a [Wired AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection#The_wired_AND_connection) connection (a diode for each circuit).